# Estructuras en Java con funciones

Tags: java

Hola es la primera vez que escribo.

Estaba haciendo una estructura de datos en **Java** *(mejor dicho simulándola)*, tengo una función para recoger datos y otra para mostrarlos *(a medio)*. El problema es que debo pasar como parámetros los datos recogidos en la función ***pedirDatos*** a la función ***mostrarDatos*** y no se como hacer que funcione.

He hecho una prueba con el **nombre**, pero el valor que me devuelve es **null**.

Estoy empezando a programar en java y me lío un poco con el tema de las funciones. Agradecería la ayuda.

Os adjunto el código.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/* Declarar una estructura cliente que disponga de los siguientes campos: nombre completo, numero de teléfono, 
numero de cuenta bancaria y cantidad de dinero. 
No olvidar que el número de una cuenta bancaria se compone del código de la entidad, código de la oficina, digito de control y 
número de cuenta propiamente dicho (este último consta de 10 dígitos).

Implementa una función para obtener los datos del cliente y otra para mostrarlos. */

class StructDatos{
    String nombre;
    String telefono;
    String codentidad;
    String codoficina;
    String digitoc;
    String numcuenta;
    float dinero;

    //CON ESTOS METODOS PODEMOS ASIGNARLE VAORES A LAS VARIABLES DE LA ESTRUCTURA
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono){
        this.telefono=telefono;
    }

    public void setCodEntidad(String codentidad){
        this.codentidad=codentidad;
    }

    public void setCodOficina(String codoficina){
        this.codoficina=codoficina;
    }

    public void setDigitoC(String digitoc){
        this.digitoc=digitoc;
    }

    public void setNumCuenta(String numcuenta){
        this.numcuenta=numcuenta;
    }

    public void setDinero(float dinero){
        this.dinero=dinero;
    }

    // CON ESTOS METODOS OBTENEMOS LOS VALORES DE LAS VARIABLES DE LA ESTRUCTURA
    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public String getTelefono(){
        return this.telefono;
    }

    public String getCodEntidad(){
        return this.codentidad;
    }

    public String getCodOficina(){
        return this.codoficina;
    }

    public String getDigitoC(){
        return this.digitoc;
    }

    public String getNumCuenta(){
        return this.numcuenta;
    }

    public float getDinero(){
        return this.dinero;
    }
}

public class Actividad24T4 {
    static void pedirDatos(StructDatos estructura){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Definios variables para recoger los datos pedidos al usuario
        String nombre, telefono, codentidad,codoficina,digitoc,numcuenta;
        float dinero;
        //Creamos la variable del tipo estructura que acabamos de definir
        //StructDatos estructura = new StructDatos();
        System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre:");
        nombre = sc.nextLine();
        estructura.setNombre(nombre);
        System.out.println("El nombre es: "+estructura.getNombre());

       /* System.out.println("Introduzca su telefono:");
          telefono=sc.nextLine();
          estructura.setTelefono(telefono);

          do {
              System.out.println("Introduzca su codigo de entidad(DEBE TENER UNA LNGITUD DE 4 DIGITOS NÚMERICOS):");
              codentidad=sc.nextLine();
              estructura.setCodEntidad(codentidad);
         } while (codentidad.length()!=4);

         do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca su codigo de oficina(DEBE TENER UNA LNGITUD DE 4 DIGITOS NÚMERICOS):");
            codoficina=sc.nextLine();
            estructura.setCodOficina(codoficina);
        } while (codoficina.length()!=4);

        do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca su digito de control(DEBE TENER UNA LNGITUD DE 2 DIGITOS NÚMERICOS):");
            digitoc=sc.nextLine();
            estructura.setDigitoC(digitoc);
        } while (digitoc.length()!=2);

        do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca su numero de cuenta(DEBE TENER UNA LNGITUD DE 10 DIGITOS NÚMERICOS):");
            numcuenta=sc.nextLine();
            estructura.setNumCuenta(numcuenta);
        } while (numcuenta.length()!=10);

        System.out.println("Introduzca su cantidad de dinero:");
        dinero=sc.nextFloat();
        estructura.setDinero(dinero);*/
    }

    static void mostrarDatos(StructDatos estructura){
        System.out.println("---CLIENTE DE UN BANCO---");
        System.out.println("Nombe: "+estructura.getNombre());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        StructDatos estructura = new StructDatos();
        Actividad24T4.pedirDatos(estructura);
        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println(estructura.getNombre());
        Actividad24T4.mostrarDatos(estructura); 
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema es que en `main` no estás creando una instancia de tu clase `Actividad24T4`, o quizá esa clase debería ser estática para poder hacer llamadas del tipo  `Actividad24T4.pedirDatos()`. Entonces o declaras `Actividad24T4` como `static` o creas una instancia de ella en el `main` y usas esa instancia para hacer la llamada a sus métodos. Otra cosa, en Java no se habla de *estructuras*, sino de ***clases***, ni se habla de *funciones*, sino de ***métodos***.

Comment: @A.Cedano No se ve claro el error en el código. Por qué el método `pedirDatos` es estático y por lo tanto es válido invocar al método de esta forma: `Actividad24T4.pedirDatos().` (ya hice la prueba)

Comment: En realidad no veo un error en el código, como comentas  @MrDave1999 es valido invocar el método de esa forma.